# Is there any API to create virtual credit card (VCC)?

Tags: api, mastercard

I've wasted my 2 hours searching about VCC API on Google. I want to know if there is any API offered by either Visa or MasterCard that allows us to create virtual credit cards and fund them?

I know it's possible. For instance, Entropay offers its user to create a Visa VCC and fund it. How do they do it? How do they create VCC? I couldn't find any API for card creation on Visa Developer's site at http://developer.visa.com or MasterCard at http://developer.mastercard.com

So if neither Visa nor MasterCard offers APIs to VCC creation then how do sites like Entropay, Bancore etc. works?

How can I get an API to create VCCs like Entropay and Bancore do?

Comment: It's up to the service provider to hand out card numbers or provide a sandbox for testing purposes.

Answer (score 10):

Try https://www.marqeta.com/ they seem to have decent API for what you want.

Comment: How can you create a global credit card and charge it via API to buy online without sharing your information? Is it possible to do such ting with Marqeta?